# javascript image rollover inside div

Tags: javascript

i have a single div 100px X 300px. What's the easiest way in JavaScript so when I hover over the div i show an image and then when i leave the div the image disappears.

for starters i thought the following would get me started but i can't seem to remove the image properly

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function MouseOver_Event(elementId) {
            var imgToCreate = document.createElement('img');
            imgToCreate.setAttribute('id', 'imgHandle');
            imgToCreate.setAttribute('src', elementId + '.png');
            imgToCreate.setAttribute('onmouseout', 'MouseOut_Event('+elementId+')');
            var targetDiv = document.getElementById(elementId);
            targetDiv.appendChild(imgToCreate);
            targetDiv.removeAttribute('onmouseover', 'MouseOver_Event');
        }
        function MouseOut_Event(elementId) {
            var imgToRemove = document.getElementById('imgHandle');
            var targetDiv = imgToRemove.parentNode();
            if (imgToRemove != null)
                targetDiv.removeChild(imgToRemove);
            targetDiv.setAttribute('onmouseover', 'MouseOut_Event(' + elementId + ')');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1" onmouseover="MouseOver_Event(this.id)"></div>
<div id="div2" onmouseover="MouseOver_Event(this.id)"></div>
<div id="div3" onmouseover="MouseOver_Event(this.id)"><img src="Div3.png" alt="test" onmouseout="MouseOut_Event(parentNode's id or something)" /></div>
</body>
```

Comment: well, for starters [parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.parentNode) is not a method so you don't need the parentheses

Comment: Why don't you specifiy the image as a background image of the div and then use css sprites to create the hover effect ? JS is nice, but sometimes there's an easier solution! Another very easy solution if you want to stick with JS, would be using jQuery as an extra module...its sooo easy to change properties with it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use **CSS** instead ?
For example:

```
#div1{background:none;}
#div1:hover{background:url('src/div1.png') no-repeat;}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're attaching your MouseOut_Event to onmouseover instead of onmouseout. But you probably don't need to be messing with dynamic event creation anyway; just add onmouseout="MouseOut_Event(this.id)" to the three divs and that should do it.